# Map control Gmap.net crashes

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework-version, gmap.net

I am using gmap.net Map control in my winform application. it is running good at developers computers but crash on clients computers Although we update all sytems. but after few minute the map is crash and give following net framework error[image]

Comment: With provided info, I can tell there is an `InvalidOperationException` thrown, It says you're modifying a collection as you're iterating over it. You can click details button to see if that provides stack trace.

Comment: but why this error not  on my system?

Comment: Well that may be depends on .Net framework changes in client machine. Post the stacktrace, otherwise you are unlikely to get help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the GMap.NET control in the past, and I ran into a similar problem. Judging by the big fat red cross in the background, the GMap.NET control has crashed during its `OnPaint` method. The `enumeration operation may not execute` error that is thrown is typically caused by modifying a collection while iterating it: this is something that most collection types in the framework do not allow.

In its `OnPaint` method, the GMap.NET control iterates numerous collections, amongst other the `GMapControl.Overlays` collection and the `GMapOverlay.Markers`, `GMapOverlay.Routes` and `GMapOverlay.Polygons` collections of these overlays. In my case, I was modifying these collections from a background thread while the control was trying to do its painting, and thus iterating these collections. This resulted in behaviour similar to what you are observing now.

I noticed that GMap.NET uses a custom collection class called `ObservableCollectionThreadSafe<T>` for all of the abovementioned collection. The name implies thread-safety and thus possible tolerance for modifications during iteration, but I haven't studied its implementation so I am not sure whether this is true. My observations seemed to indicate otherwise, but this was quite a while ago.

At the time, I solved my problems by [invoking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) modifications to the abovementioned collections to the GUI thread (by lack of a synchronization object to lock on). Invoking ensures that the modifications cannot possibly run simultaneously with the `GMapControl.OnPaint` method, which will always run on the GUI thread as well.

As to why you are not observing this behaviour on your machine: this could be due to numerous reasons. Perhaps you got lucky, perhaps you're using the application differently than the client, etc.

You can probably get more helpful answers to your question on the [GMap.NET discussions forum](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions) by the way.

Comment: This was useful. I spent quite a bit of time on this issue ... Use of invoke is a good idea. There's a similar issue I also ran into: new GMarkerGoogle can cause "object is in use elsewhere" exception if simultaneously invoked in different threads. Serializing it with invocation fixes it.

Comment: This is exactly that I also concluded, after looking at the code (here: https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps). Im thinking a lock would do.

Comment: As a reference, another solution by locking: https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/issues/99

Comment: I actually dont think a lock will do, as the collections are public properties, and locking on those isnt a good idea. I am instead creating local, temporary, Lists, that I foreach over, instead of the public props.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you have to disable invalidation whilst updating or adding markers or polygons:

```
MyMap.HoldInvalidation = True

'
' Add markers or polygons now
' 

MyMap.HoldInvalidation = False      ' Not sure if this line is needed
MyMap.Refresh()
```

Answer (score -1):

you are missing the dll which are required to run the application, i would suggest to copy the complete bin folder on your local system and then try to run the application. if you have created msi package them make sure the dependency are added properly.